# Questions about using Accelerate.framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, macos

I had a few questions about Accelerate framework.

What is the difference between Single Precision Float, Single-Precision Complex, Double-Precision Float, and Double-Precision Complex? And what should I be using for a simple struct like:

```
struct vector
{
   float x;
   float y;
   float z;
};
```

Also can someone explain what each of the arguments to this sample function mean?

```
void cblas_cdotc_sub (
   const int N,
   const void *X,
   const int incX,
   const void *Y,
   const int incY,
   void *dotc
);
```

Apple's descriptions are a little unclear to me. What do they mean by the length for N? Is that the size of the vector in bytes? Or the actual spatial length of the vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complex variables are 2 dimensional quantities, normally treated as the real and imaginary parts of complex numbers in arithmetic/math operations.

IEEE single and double floats allow differing amounts of binary precision (roughly the amount of significant digits without rounding error), very approximately 7 or so digits for single, around double that for double, plus a wider exponent range as well.

But single float arithmetic runs a lot faster on current iOS devices than does double (unlike the Simulator, where they may both run more the same speed.)

Apple's descriptions may require some basic knowledge of C data types, arrays and structures, and the mathematical theory of complex variables.  I'd start by reading some books on basic C programming and numerical algorithms in C.

Comment: I understand what it meant by single and double precision I was more asking what the complex meant but thanks for the clarification. Now any ideas on the N part of that function?

Comment: Nevermind I found some stronger documentation and figured it out.

Comment: @Justin - In addition to what hotpaw2 describes here, you might find the [source code examples](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/SampleCode/SampleCode.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005147-CH205-CIAEJIGF) in the vDSP Programming Guide to be useful.

Comment: @Justin - You'll also want to watch the WWDC 2010 video session 202 - The Accelerate framework for iPhone OS.

Comment: Thanks for the tips I am downloading that video!